# Advice to resolve window dependency when running in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to extend my browser-side library's runtime environment to node.js. I implemented the Universal Module Definition (UMD) pattern to do that. It works with AMD implementation and `<script>` but doesn't work in node.js since there is no `window`.

The dependencies in question are `WebSocket`, `EventSource`, `XMLHttpRequest`, `document`. The detail is described in here: https://github.com/flowersinthesand/portal/issues/115 So what is the best approach to resolve window dependency in node.js? I have though the following way to do that. Since I'm new to node.js, these are somewhat unfamiliar and I don't know which way is natural. Though I'm trying to support node.js, I don't want to change too much something.

The following code snippet comes from https://github.com/flowersinthesand/portal/blob/master/portal.js

**Using jsdom**

```
(function(root, factory) {
        if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
                // AMD
                define(function() {
                    // Passes the window
                    return factory(root);
                });
        } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
                // Node
                module.exports = factory(require('jsdom').something);
        } else {
                // Browser globals, Window
                root.portal = factory(root);
        }
}(this, function(window) {
```

If the jsdom supports the above dependencies well, this looks best. If it works, however, I wonder why client of sockjs, socket.io and engine.io don't use jsdom. Maybe, they are for node rather than browser? performance?

**Making window as a plain object of dependency**

```
(function(root, factory) {
        if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
                // AMD
                define(function() {
                    // Passes the window
                    return factory(root);
                });
        } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
                // Node
                module.exports = factory({
                    WebSocket: require('package name for WebSocket').something,
                    EventSource: require('package name for EventSource').something,
                    document: require('jsdom').hmm,
                    // ...
                });
        } else {
                // Browser globals, Window
                root.portal = factory(root);
        }
}(this, function(window) {
```

It looks picky and somewhat uncomfortable to make a group of dependency, window, But, I want to preserve current code if possible. Also, jsdom may be required as well to resolve document used to do HTTP request by script tag when XMLHttpRequest can't work due to cross-domain or unloading event and this situation includes IE 6. It's possible to separate logic using document to use something supported in node and script tag in browser checking what the current runtime is, but it's big change for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function(root, factory) {
        if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
                // AMD
                define(function() {
                        return factory(root);
                });
        } else if (typeof exports === "object") {
                // Node
                module.exports = factory(function() {
                        // Prepare the window powered by jsdom
                        var window = require("jsdom").jsdom().createWindow();
                        window.WebSocket = require("ws");
                        window.EventSource = require("eventsource");
                        return window;
                }());
                // node-XMLHttpRequest 1.x conforms XMLHttpRequest Level 1 but can perform a cross-domain request
                module.exports.support.corsable = true;
        } else {
                // Browser globals, Window
                root.portal = factory(root);
        }
}(this, function(window) {
```